# Removing a section of vinyl fence with wood beams inside posts

Tags: fence, vinyl

I Googled it, and found a lot of videos about removing sections from the fence.  There is also [How do I temporarily remove section of vinyl fence?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32764/how-do-i-temporarily-remove-section-of-vinyl-fence)

However, all of this does not seem to apply in my case.  When I open the top of the post, it is not empty with rails protruding inside it.  All I see is a wooden beam that fills the entire interior of the post.  It also doesn't look as if the railings go into the post at all: there is a tiny gap between the railing and the post, although "something" inside the railing does connect to the post.

The actual problem I'm trying to fix is melted plastic.  I bought the house this way.  It's unsightly, and I would like to replace this section.

Here are the pictures.
[image: Inside the post]
[image: Post and railing]
[image: Section with a melt]

Comment: You can hide that melted section behind a grill ;^)

Comment: Yeah, and my wife will probably grow some ivies on that fence.  Still, I'm curious how hard it is to replace it.

Comment: What does the bottom of the rail look like? Is there a split there of some sort? What is your end goal? If it's just to get rid of the melted cover, then simply cut off the cover and pitch it.

Comment: Yeah, thee are 2 parallel gaps on the bottom of the rail.  Its top may be snapped into the bottom.